# unable to create table in database

Tags: iphone, sqlite

When i am trying to create 2 table in database only "sql_stmt" is working and "sql_stmt1" is not working in below code(but it showing that it is executed).

So only one table is creating but i want to create two table.

How can i create two table at a same in database.

```
const char *sql_stmt = "CREATE TABLE DOSAGE_HISTORY50(PILL_NAME VARCHAR(100),PILL_PER_DOSE NUMBER,PILLS_REMAINING NUMBER,SCHEDULE VARCHAR(100),DIRECTION VARCHAR(100))";
        const char *sql_stmt1 = "CREATE TABLE DOCTOR (ID varchar(20))";


        if (sqlite3_exec(pillDB, sql_stmt, NULL, NULL, &errMsg) != SQLITE_OK) {

        }

    if (sqlite3_exec(pillDB, sql_stmt1, NULL, NULL, &errMsg) != SQLITE_OK) {

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're executing sql_stmt1 two times, trying to create table doctor.  I think your first if statement should be:

```
if (sqlite3_exec(pilldDB, sql_stmt...
```